# Convert DJB Hash To 64 Bit

Tags: c++, c, hash

Would Dan Bernstein's hash function still function properly if I was using a 64 bit unsigned integer?

```
uint64
hash_djb2(register uchar *str, register size_t length) {
    register uint64 hash = 5381L;
    while (length--) {
        hash = ((hash << 5L) + hash) + *str++; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the distribution across all 2^64 possible values will be the same as the 32-bit version, but one important property still holds.  The multiplier `33` does not share any common divisors with 2^64.  As a result, all characters run through the hash will still have an affect on the final result.  In other words, the hash result for these two strings will be different:

```
hash("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") => 0x87b2af4e3d92de7a
hash("baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") => 0xd496edbee1219cfb
```

It should still be a useful hash function.  And of course, I can't help but wonder why you need hash values this large.  A very large hash table?  Or some other use?

Comment: I'm making a hash table that can possible run over 4 billion rows (not very likely, but a possibility)..  also, lower possibility of a collision is nice...

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity.  It sounds like you will be pushing some boundaries; those can be the good types of projects.

Answer (score 11):

The djb hash function is based on a [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which has the form x = (a·x + c) mod m.

By inspecting the function, we realise that `a = 33`, `c = input` in the case of djb but the modulo is a bit hidden because it is stated by the type of the variable **hash**, *unsigned long* in it's original form, which contains 32 bits of data. When the value goes beyond the value of an unsigned long, it overflows and continues, thus a modulo of 2^32.

According to Knuth in his The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms on chapter 3.2.1, m must be divisible by all prime factors of (a-1) for an Linear Congruential Generator to have a maximal period (period = modulo) (as well as other facts already taken into account by Mr. Bernstein). Since having a `m = 2^64` introduces no new prime factor, since by definition `2` is a prime number of both `2^32` and `2^64`, this rule is satisfied.

You would then, with this new hash algorithm, be able to get a period as long as your modulo, meaning you would cover all possible values of an 64 bit integer.

Please keep in mind though that altering any mathematical value of an algorithm can't be done lightly. A completely new statistical analysis is required to fully understand the flaws and benefits of your new algorithm, even if you only changed one variable of it. You can't simply change values and hope to get the same features as the original Linear Congruential Generator. Statistical characteristics such as entropy and collisions won't be retained from the former algorithm. You then **can't** claim to have implemented an djb algorithm, neither quote any statistical performance of djb to prove anything on your implementation.